SonarCloud Analyzes .cs Files but Does Not Display Them in UI
I’m building a .NET application in an Azure DevOps pipeline with Visual Studio build task, along with SonarCloud's Prepare Analysis Configuration and Run Code Analysis tasks. The analysis runs successfully, and the .cs files are indexed, but some of them do not appear in the SonarCloud UI.
The pipeline logs confirm that the files are indexed and analyzed by SonarCloud, and the analysis completes successfully. Here is the log:
2024-09-20T15:39:50.6439225Z "C:\\a\\1\\s\\src\\AL.Data.Starter\\Repositories\\MyALRepository.cs",\
2024-09-20T15:40:05.7193722Z 15:40:05.718 DEBUG: 'src/AL.Data.Starter/Repositories/MyALRepository.cs' generated metadata with charset 'UTF-8'
2024-09-20T15:40:05.7194319Z 15:40:05.718 DEBUG: 'src\AL.Data.Starter\Repositories\MyALRepository.cs' indexed with language 'cs'
2024-09-20T15:41:35.4408210Z 15:41:35.439 DEBUG: Adding normal issue S2325: C:\a\1\s\src\AL.Data.Starter\Repositories\MyALRepository.cs
2024-09-20T15:41:35.4377030Z 15:41:35.436 DEBUG: Adding normal issue S1006: C:\a\1\s\src\AL.Data.Starter\Repositories\MyALRepository.cs
2024-09-20T15:41:35.4421856Z 15:41:35.441 DEBUG: Adding normal issue S2325: C:\a\1\s\src\AL.Data.Starter\Repositories\MyALRepository.cs
2024-09-20T15:41:35.7572249Z 15:41:35.756 DEBUG: Incremental PR analysis: Adding hash for 'src/AL.Data.Starter/Repositories/MyALRepository.cs' to the cache.
2024-09-20T15:41:39.8359120Z 15:41:39.834 DEBUG: Detection of duplications for C:/a/1/s/src/AL.Data.Starter/Repositories/MyALRepository.cs

Other files show up, but some specific files are missing from the SonarCloud UI.

What could cause specific cs file not appeared in the ui? how CAN i DEBUG THIS?

Hi @ZSH, can you please share your yaml to better check the issue? You can try to add sonar.verbose=true to the SonarCloudPrepare task’s extraProperties argument to get more details. By the way, you can ask this question here to get more professional technical support on SonarCloud.
